# Latex: use color without defining a new color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tabularray

Is it possible to use a new color without defining a new color like `\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{a65dbd}`? It is indeed cumbersome to use when the color is used only once, and can easily lead to conflicts if multiple parts of the file use the same color name for different colors (in particular, no error is given if we use `\definecolor{mycolor}` twice, so the colors only appears to be wrong for no apparent reason).

As HTML colors are easy to copy/paste between programs, I'd love to be able to do something like:

```
\textcolor{HTML(00AA00)}{\textbf{This is not working}}
```

**MWE:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{a65dbd} % Equal to RGB(166,93,189).
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textcolor{mycolor}{\textbf{This is my color but annoying to use.}}\\
\textcolor{red!65!green!36!blue!74!}{\textbf{This is better but not accurate nor easily copy/pastable.}}\\
\textcolor[HTML]{a65dbd}{\textbf{This is working, but not generalizable (tikz, tabularray\dots).}}\\
\verb|\tikz \node[text=[HTML]{a65dbd]{This is not working};|
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Phelype proposed in comments to use `\textcolor[HTML]{00AA00}{...}`, unfortunately it does not generalize to other commands. For instance, this is not working in tikz, nor in tabularray cell colors:

```
\tikz \node[text=[HTML]{a65dbd]{This is not working};
```

Wouldn't it be possible to define a generic color taking arguments (like `green!50!white` which works for both tikz, tabularray, textcolor...) but taking as input an HTML color description?

**EDIT**

I created a feature request here https://github.com/latex3/xcolor/issues/13 but if someone has a solution is the meantime, I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133062/discussion-on-question-by-tobiasbora-latex-use-color-without-defining-a-new-col).

Comment: Even the HTML color code doesn't get real HTML colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not a big fan of @L.J.R.'s approach, the example below extends [his/her answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629719) to gain support for `tikz`.

Notable improvements:

- By patching internal of `\colorlet`, it now supports `tikz`.
- Skipping patching when the color expression doesn't contain `|`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{unravel}
\unravelsetup{max-action=1000, max-input=1000, max-output=1000}
\long\def\beginunravel#1\endunravel{\unravel{#1}}
\providecommand\beginunravel{}
\def\endunravel{}

\makeatletter

% The following set of ugly patches based on
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629719
% extend xcolor <expr> (see `texdoc xcolor`, Table 4) to
%   <expr> ::= <mode> "|" <spec>
%            | <original expr>
% and add constraint that a (user-defined) color name must NOT contaion `|`

% for \color, \textcolor, etc.
\xpretocmd\@declaredcolor
  {\my@hack@definetempcolor{#1}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\def\my@hack@color{\xglobal\definecolor}

% for \colorlet (used by tikz)
\xpretocmd\XC@col@rlet
  {\my@hack@definetempcolor{#4}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

% shared inner helper macros

% if color expression #1 contains `|` and is an undefined color name, execute
%   \xglobal\definecolor{#1}{<#1 pre |>}{<#1 post |>}
\def\my@hack@definetempcolor#1{%
  % a bit normalization: remove all spaces from #1
  \expanded{\my@hack@@definetempcolor{\zap@space#1 \@empty}}}%
\protected\def\my@hack@@definetempcolor#1{%
  \in@|{#1}%
  \ifin@
    \@ifundefinedcolor{#1}{\my@hack@splitcolor#1\@nil{\xglobal\definecolor}}{}%
  \fi
}

\def\my@hack@splitcolor#1|#2\@nil#3{#3{#1|#2}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
{ \color{rgb|0.5,0.7,0.9}TEXT }

\textcolor{HTML|a65dbd}{TEXT}

\begin{tblr}{row{1} = {bg={HTML|11AA33}}}
  Alpha & Beta & Gamma
\end{tblr}

\tikz[line width=3pt]
  \draw[{HTML|a65dbd}, fill={rgb|0.5,0.7,0.9}] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, this should be merged upstream!

Comment: @tobiasBora Current patch is still brute. Another set of patch entrances is when `xcolor` wants to raise error ``Undefined color `xxx'``. Also active-char handling need to be added, to live with the world if the newly introduced reserved character in color expr (here `|`) is active. Also I've find a perhaps better way: provide a new color function, so one can use `\color{.>rgb,.1,.5,.9}` (need one new function per color model) or `\color{.>raw,rgb,.1,.5,.9}` (need only one new function). Any expr before `>` will be parsed but dropped. Need time to try and implement all these.

Answer (score 5):

At least the following dirty code works for `tabularray` package :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\pretocmd{\@declaredcolor}{\my@hack@color{#1}}{}{}

\def\my@hack@color#1{\@ifundefined{\@backslashchar color@#1}{\MyDefineColor{#1}}{\relax}}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\NewDocumentCommand \MyDefineColor { m } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpa_seq {|} {#1}
  %\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \exp_args:Nnxx \definecolor{#1} { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1} } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2} }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{ \color{rgb|0.5,0.7,0.9}TEXT }

\textcolor{HTML|a65dbd}{TEXT}

\begin{tblr}{row{1} = {bg={HTML|11AA33}}}
  Alpha & Beta & Gamma
\end{tblr}

%% This is not working:
%\tikz \path[draw={HTML|012acd}] (0,0) -- (1,1);

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks really cool, thanks! To bad it fails with tikz. I'll just put a +1 so far, hoping to see a solution that also works with tikz!

Comment: @tobiasBora: why do you want to use a hammersledge like TiKZ for such a simple layout?

Comment: @Bernard Of course I don't plan to use tikz to color a simple text. But I do like to use multiple colors for my tikz drawings. For the sake of simplicity I include some MWE, but in real life my diagram will certainly be more complex than `\tikz \path[draw={HTML+012acd}] (0,0) -- (1,1);`

Comment: @tobiasBora: It can be done with a simple table and `\rowcolor` Other than that,  you can use `colors by name` with `xcolor`  and find already existing colour names corresponding to what you want.

Comment: @Bernard I doubt you can make any tikz drawing with a simple table and `\rowcolor`, just try to create a gradient-filled ellipse with `\rowcolor`... Concerning `colors by name`, as already explained they describe only 0.03% of all the colors you can get with the HTML notation. And when I use a palette or gimp to find a precise color I like, I don't want to spend hours trying to find equivalent names, I just want to use its HTML name.

Comment: This introduces ambiguity to `xcolor`'s color expression, since `+` is a valid character in `<postfix>` (see `texdoc xcolor`, sec. 2.3.2 "Meaning of standard color expressions").

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks. I have replaced `+` with `|`.

Comment: Both `color` and `xcolor` has been modified to be `\escapechar` safe (see [`latex2e#659`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/659)), hence the `\@ifundefined{\string\color@#1}{...}{...}` could be similarly changed to `\@ifundefined{\@backslashchar color@#1}{...}{...}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For `tikz` and packages based on it (and `pgfkeys`), the following new key handler `/.raw color` may help.

Usages:

- `\draw[<color>]` -> `\draw[.raw color={<color model>}{<color spec>}]`
- `key=<color>` -> `key/.raw color={<color model>}{<color spec>}`

To support `\draw[<extended color spec>]` and/or `key=<extended color spec>`, one has to patch several places of `tikz`, and maybe even `pgf`, which I doubt it's worth.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newcount\pgfutil@colorcnt

%   \pgfkeys{key/.raw color={rgb}{1,0,0}}
% is equivalent to
%   \definecolor{<name>}{rgb}{1,0,0}
%   \pgfkeys{key=<name>}
% where <name> is `pgf@color@rgb@1,0,0`
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.raw color/.code 2 args={%
  \expandafter\pgfkeys@rawcolor\expanded{{pgf@color@\pgfkeys@zap@space #1@#2 \@empty}}{#1}{#2}%
}}

% #1 = (internal) color name, #2 = color model, #3 = color spec
\def\pgfkeys@rawcolor#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\xglobal % for efficiency concerns, define the color globally
                       % note \xglobal is provided by `xcolor`, hence importable
  \pgfutil@definecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \edef\pgf@expanded@path{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}% was `\the\pgfkeys@pathtoks`
  % Note `/tikz/<name>` is different from `tikz/.cd, <name>`. Only the latter 
  % will be directed to `/tikz/.unknown` hence parse color name correctly.
  \ifx\pgf@expanded@path\pgfkeys@defaultpath@tikz@text
    \pgfkeysalso{{#1}}%
  \else
    \pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath={#1}}%
  \fi
}

% helper, the same as \zep@space in latex2e
\def\pgfkeys@zap@space#1 #2{%
  #1%
  \ifx#2\@empty\else\expandafter\pgfkeys@zap@space\fi
  #2}

\def\pgfkeys@defaultpath@tikz@text{/tikz}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
  \draw[red, fill=blue]
    (0,0) rectangle +(1,1) node[text=black!30] {node text};
  \draw[.raw color={rgb}{1,0,0}, fill/.raw color={HTML}{0000FF}]
    (2,0) rectangle +(1,1) node[text/.raw color={cmyk}{0,0,0,.3}] {node text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\tcbset{nobeforeafter}
\tcbox[colback=green!50]{tcbox content}\qquad
\tcbox[colback/.raw color={rgb}{.5,1,.5}]{tcbox content}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks super cool, thanks a lot! This should be integrated in tikz ;-) By any chance, I guess you don't know how to improve the answer from L.J.R so that it also works with tikz without a need for the new `.raw color` key? This way I don't need to think about which answer I should accept :-P

Comment: @tobiasBora I think it's possible, but a more robust way (that is fully backward-compatible) to extend `xcolor`'s color expression parser is needed.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, it also can be done with very simple tools: `xcolor`, `cellspace` and a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{18pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{18pt}

\begin{document}

{\centering \Huge\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{llSl}
\color{PowderBlue} TEXT \\
\color{MediumOrchid} TEXT \\
\rowcolor{MediumSeaGreen!60!OliveDrab} \enspace Alpha\enspace &\enspace Beta\enspace &\enspace Gamma\enspace
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry I can't find any relation with my initial question… The whole point of the work started by L.J.R is to provide a syntax `HTML+a65dbd` so that we can use this in place of any color without using definecolor. Here you try to use a combinaison of existing colors, but as explained in the question in has many troubles. In particular it can't be copy/pasted from other softwares and it is hard to produce a precise color that way. For instance your green seems darker than LJR's one.

Comment: As you've deleted the image from your initial post, I tried to make the colour from memory. Anyway, with xcolor, it's easy to adjust  a colour close to what you have in mind to something quite close.

Comment: I agree with the OP's question:  color names are silly and a waste of time.  I want to be able to write `\color{HTML+abcdef}` instead of defining a color name.