Multirow colour and vertical alignment using tabularx
I have a table that is working fine. However, when I add the attribute of colour to the third column on the second row (the one that says "plane"), the text aligns to the bottom of the multi row instead of aligning vertically to the centre of said row. If you remove the colour it behaves correctly. Any idea how to fix this?
Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \small
         \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=1.0\hsize}Y|>{\hsize=1.0\hsize}Y|>{\hsize=1.0\hsize}Y|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{d3d3d3}\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Spatial planes}}\\ \hline 
            \cellcolor[HTML]{ececec}gain & \cellcolor[HTML]{ececec}reverb &  \cellcolor[HTML]{ececec}  \\   
            \cellcolor[HTML]{ececec}A& \cellcolor[HTML]{ececec}B& \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{ececec}}{plane}\\ \hline       
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}


I suggest you change \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{ececec}}{plane} to \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{ececec}{plane}}.

TL;DR
Your original table, written using tabularx, was functional but had some limitations in terms of alignment and maintainability. I improved it by rewriting it with the tabularray package, which simplifies alignment and styling while enhancing clarity. However, the tabularray package is generally slower than older counterparts like tabularx because of its extensive use of macro expansion. This performance impact is particularly noticeable on the free tier of Overleaf, which has limited computational resources. If performance is a concern, you may prefer sticking with tabularx.
I also noticed that you are using a floating table with the specifier h! (\begin{table}[h!]). This isn't ideal if your goal is to control the precise positioning of the table. Floating tables are better suited for scenarios where placement flexibility is acceptable. If you need exact placement simply don't use the table environment.
References: `h' float specifier changed to `ht' warning when not attempting to specify a float, How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?
Improved version of the original code
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | Y | Y | Y | }
\hline
     \rowcolor{gray!40} \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Spatial planes}}\\
\hline
     \rowcolor{gray!10} gain & reverb & \\   
     \rowcolor{gray!10} A & B & \multirow{-2}{*}{plane}\\
\hline       
\end{tabularx}


Issues in the Original Table

Alignment Problems: The \multirow command caused the text "plane" to align at the bottom of the merged rows rather than centering vertically.
Manual Row Styling: Using \rowcolor for each row makes it less flexible and harder to maintain.
Limited Control: While tabularx is powerful, it lacks modern styling options, and combining it with extra commands (like \multirow) increases complexity.

Improved Version with tabularray
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={ *{3}{X[c,m]} }, % Columns centered horizontally and vertically
  vline{1-Z}, hline{1-2,Z}, % Vertical and horizontal lines
  cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{}, % First cell spans all 3 columns
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!40}, % Header row with bold font and gray background
  row{2-Z} = {bg=gray!10}, % All other rows with light gray background
}
  Spatial planes &&\\
  {gain\\A} & {reverb\\B} & plane \\
\end{tblr}


Improvements

Better Alignment Handling: tabularray natively centers content both horizontally and vertically using X[c,m], eliminating alignment issues without requiring \multirow.

Global Styling: Row styles (e.g., background color) are applied globally using row{1} and row{2-Z} commands, making the table more readable and maintainable.

Simplified Code: Combining multi-line text (e.g., {gain\\A}) avoids using \multirow, reducing complexity.

Enhanced Flexibility: The modern tabularray package provides more advanced features and customization options compared to tabularx.


Warning if compilation speed is important (e.g. if you compile on overleaf)
While tabularray improves the table's readability and maintainability, it is significantly slower due to the overhead of macro expansion. If your document is large or performance is critical, consider whether the benefits of an easy interface outweigh the slowdown. Alternatively, stick with tabularx for better performance.

Full code
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the problem
\documentclass[preview, margin=2mm]{standalone}

% packages needed for first solution
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% exposes \rowcolor command
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

% 2. packages needed for second solution
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | Y | Y | Y | }
\hline
     \rowcolor{gray!40} \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Spatial planes}}\\
\hline
     \rowcolor{gray!10} gain & reverb & \\   
     \rowcolor{gray!10} A & B & \multirow{-2}{*}{plane}\\
\hline       
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tblr}{
  % columns centered horizontally and vertically
  colspec={ *{3}{X[c,m]} },
  % lines
  vline{1-Z}, hline{1-2,Z},
  % first cell takes 3 columns
  cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{},
  % row styles
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!40},
  row{2-Z} = {bg=gray!10},
}
  Spatial planes &&\\
  {gain\\A} & {reverb\\B} & plane \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


tabularray is slower everywhere, not only on overleaf. It also doesn't properly support tagging yet.

that's what I meant to say, but rereading it, I can see why it might have been interpreted that way. I hope this version is clearer now :)

well speed doesn't matter only on overleaf. So perhaps you should write "warning if compilation speed is important (e.g. if you compile on overleaf)"

Done, thanks for the suggestion!

Here is a solution with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[c]X[c]X[c]|}[vlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[HTML]{d3d3d3}{1}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{ececec}{2,3}
\Body
  \Hline
  \Block{1-3}{\textbf{Spatial planes}}\\ \Hline 
  gain & reverb & \Block{2-1}{plane} \\   
  A    & B      & \\ \Hline       
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

You need several compilations.

In your case, it's also possible to create a tabular with only two rows by using a multi-row block for gain A and revert B, with, maybe, a more adequate vertical spacing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[c]X[c]X[c]|}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[HTML]{d3d3d3}{1}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{ececec}{2}
\Body
  \Block{1-3}{\textbf{Spatial planes}} \\ 
  \Block{}{gain\\ A} & \Block{}{reverb\\ B} & plane \\   
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}



Edit:
If you for some reason persist to use HTML color model than solution with use of the tblr of tabularray package instead of tabularx is not so simple because  tblr doesn't support this color model directly. However, it can be used by hack provided by tabularray package author on the following way:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{etoolbox}     % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629708/
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pretocmd{\@declaredcolor}{\my@hack@color{#1}}{}{}

\def\my@hack@color#1{\@ifundefined{\@backslashchar color@#1}{\MyDefineColor{#1}}{\relax}}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\NewDocumentCommand \MyDefineColor { m } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpa_seq {|} {#1}
  %\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \exp_args:Nnxx \definecolor{#1} { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1} } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
%\small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{3}{X[c, m]}},
             cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, bg={HTML|d3d3d3}},
             row{2}  = {bg={HTML|ececec}}
             }
Spatial planes  &                   &           \\
{gain\\ B}      &   {reverb\\ B}    &   plane   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



Your first code snippet won’t run unless you load xcolor first, as it’s still needed to handle colors in tabularray.

@EmanueleNardi, I remove the first example since I now recognize that is almost the same as in last in your answer.
